# Get screen brightness level in Windows 8.1 project

Tags: windows, win-universal-app, screen-brightness

Is it possible to get device (monitor/tablet/phone) current brightness level in Windows 8.1 project or Universal Windows app using C#?

I got a code which queries from System.Management dll.

```
static int GetBrightness()
        {
            System.Management.ManagementScope s = new System.Management.ManagementScope("root\\WMI");

            System.Management.SelectQuery q = new System.Management.SelectQuery("WmiMonitorBrightness");

            System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(s, q);

            System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mos.Get();

            byte curBrightness = 0;
            foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject o in moc)
            {
                curBrightness = (byte)o.GetPropertyValue("CurrentBrightness");
                break;
            }

            moc.Dispose();
            mos.Dispose();

            return (int)curBrightness;
        }
```

But that's not working in app projects.

Comment: The monitor brightness is not available to UWP apps. (What would the brightness of a device with no monitor [e.g., HoloLens] even mean?)

Comment: Actually, I meant is Screen brightness level of a device

Comment: You can get the brightness of a Lamp device. See [the Lamp sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=620558).